# Printing form id inside table

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 form inside my html body. all form are created with different formid. example

```
<form method="post" id="formid1" name="abc">
    <input type="button" value="xyz" style="height: 115px; width: 300px;">
</form>
.
.
.
<form method="post" id="formid10" name="abc10">
    <input type="button" value="xyz10" style="height: 115px; width: 300px;">
</form>
```

I want to print the form name (abc, abc1.... abc10) inside a table. How can I achieve that?

I tried using a javascript function by createing a button as:

```
 <div>
     <button id="hide1" onclick="myFunction()"Service </button>
 </div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("formid1").name;
        document.getElementById("demomain").innerHTML = "The name of the form is: " + x;
    }
</script>
```

but I am not able to print that inside a table. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like:

```
var names = null;
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for (var i = 0; i <= forms.length; i++) {
   names += "The name of the form is: " + forms[i].getAttribute('name');
   document.getElementById("demomain").innerHTML = names;
}
```

### [See DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tosiporedugu/1/edit)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i print these value inside table(in <td> tag) @Dev01

Comment: just give your td an id and use that in `document.getElementById("demomain").innerHTML = names;`

Answer (score 0):

For me you code is working.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("formid1").name;
    document.getElementById("demomain").innerHTML = "The name of the form is: " + x;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/7jdjg7wo/2/)